# Create error messages Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, error-handling

Ok, I am currently a Grade 11 student thats taking IT. I am trying to finish a Practical assignment but I ran into a bit of a problem, the textbook I am using didn't show me how to Create an error message if the user did not enter data into a RichEdit. Could anyone advise me on how to do this? thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: E.g. this way `if RichEdit1.Text = '' then MessageDlg('The field cannot be empty!', mtError, [mbOK], 0)` in an event which will do the validation (usually `OnExit` event).

Comment: Thanks! that was fast... trying it now.

Comment: @DNgentle One advice would be to be proactive, Use your resources available to you before putting your guns down :-) .

Comment: What did your instructor say when you asked in class?

Comment: @RobKennedy Indeed the instructor may know exactly where to look in your textbook

Comment: @JerryDodge I'm actually home schooled, so I'm teaching myself... TLama's solution was the one i needed... but thanks for all the tips

Answer (score 4):

This is how you raise a generic exception (using the `SysUtils.Exception` class):

```
raise Exception.Create('Error Message');
```

An unhandled exception causes the execution path to escape into a default exception handler inside of the Delphi RTL, which will then display the value of the `Exception.Message` to the user.

You could even handle your own exception like this:

```
try
  ...
  raise Exception.Create('Error Message');
  ...
except
  on E: Exception do
  begin
    ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

You wouldn't actually do this though. You raise exceptions so that code calling your method can handle the error.

Raise an exception if you want to handle the error elsewhere (in the caller).

To simply display the system standard error dialog, you can use `MessageDlg`:

```
MessageDlg('Error Message', mtError, [mbOK], 0);
```

The caption of the window in this case is simply "Error". If you must set a caption, use `CreateMessageDialog`:

```
with CreateMessageDialog('Error Message', mtError, [mbOK], mbOK) do
begin
  try
    Caption := 'Error Caption';
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Release;
  end;
end;
```

The `Exception` class is in `System.SysUtils`. `MessageDlg` and `CreateMessageDialog` are in `Vcl.Dialogs`.

Or use the `TApplication.MessageBox()` method:

```
Application.MessageBox('Error Message', 'Error Caption', MB_OK or MB_ICONERROR);
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you use `TApplication.MessageBox()` or `Winapi.MessageBox()` instead of `MessageDlg()`, you can set the caption as an input parameter.

Comment: Another thing to consider is creating your own exception types, such as `ENoContent` which allows a more systematic way of catching certain types of exceptions and then universally handled in one place with one message box, etc.

Comment: But before the message from the Delphi RTL, depeinding on how Windows is configured, unhandled exceptions first go to "Windows is checking for a solution to the problem"