# How to put a ShowMessage if conditional evaluates to false?

Tags: delphi, if-statement, listbox

I'm trying to display a message in the case where my `if` detect a name that has already been inserted into another listbox. This is what I have tried so far:

```
procedure TFrmProjetos.buttonaddusersClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  item: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to listxallusers.Items.Count - 1 do
  begin
    item:= listxallusers.Items[i];
    if listxallusers.Selected[i] and (listtxusersinproj.Items.IndexOf(item) = -1) then
    begin
      listtxusersinproj.Items.Add(item);
    end
    else
      Application.MessageBox('User already record.','Warning!',MB_OK+MB_ICONWARNING);
    Abort;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Tell us what happens and what you expect to happen so we can help you.

Comment: It looks as if a `begin` is missing in the `else` clause. Is this really your exact code? What is the question anyway?

Comment: I corrected your indenting. From the looks of it, the abort statement will be triggered after the first execution of the loop. It's not part of the else block.

Comment: sorry for delay, the ans for @Ravaut123 is exacly wat I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also loop into the list and add only the not existing user in the record and show the user that are not inserted in the record.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lstUserRecord: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
begin
  lstUserRecord:= TStringList.Create();
  try
    for i := 0 to listxallusers.Items.Count - 1 do
    begin
      if listxallusers.Selected[i] then
      begin
        if (UserInList(listxallusers.Items[i])) then
        begin
          lstUserRecord.add(listxallusers.Items[i]);
        end;
      end;
    end;
    if (lstUserRecord.count>0) then
    begin
      raise Exception.Create(format('Users already in record: %s',[lstUserRecord.CommaText]));
    end;
  finally
    lstUserRecord.Free;
  end;
end;

function TForm1.UserInList(AUser: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result:= (listtxusersinproj.Items.IndexOf(AUser) > -1);
  if not Result then
  begin
    listtxusersinproj.Items.Add(AUser);
  end
end;
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I change the title of Exception.Create?, in my case is a my project title.

Comment: @Artur_Indio: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252589/create-error-messages-delphi-7

Answer (score 1):

The `if` clause contains an `and`. This means that the warning will be given if either of the conditions is false, i.e. also if `listxallusers.Selected[i]` is false. Is that what you want?

I think this is what you want:

```
  item:= listxallusers.Items[i];
  if listxallusers.Selected[i] then
  begin
    if listtxusersinproj.Items.IndexOf(item) = -1 then
    begin
      listtxusersinproj.Items.Add(item);
    end
    else
    begin
      Application.MessageBox('User already record.','Warning!',MB_OK+MB_ICONWARNING);
      Abort;
    end;
  end;
```

Personally, I think that an `Abort` is a pretty harsh reaction. I would remove it.

Comment: I agree with this, `break` would be much better than `abort`.

Comment: I may be wrong, but can't multiple items be selected? In that case, `Break` would be wrong too.

Comment: That is true. In that case, it would probably make sense to build up a list and display a single message with the error and the list of duplicates.